# Accidentally forgot network, tried to reconnect. Taking too long to reconnect with CORRECT network key

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, connection

I accidentally forgot my home network on my laptop while trying to forget a different one (I have Windows 8.1), and every time I try to reconnect using the positively correct network key, it gives me that dreaded message, "connecting to the network is taking longer than usual." I've restarted my computer twice, used the troubleshooters, and nothing's working. I can't reconnect. I need my connection back *today.* Is there anything simple I can do to fix it?

Comment: Try going to Device Manager > Network adapters > Disabling your network adapter and enabling it again.

Comment: Does it connect to ANY other SSIDs, even not at your home?

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.